# IDA - Decoding this "XORed"? string automatically in psuedocode

Tags: ida, disassembly, idapython

```
__m128i ModuleName;
__m128i ProcName;

ModuleName.m128i_i64[0] = 0x3E4D19089E7D5EDi64;
ModuleName.m128i_i64[1] = 0xD8855EB576AF36A0ui64;
ProcName.m128i_i64[0] = 0x6F80FFFCE583A183i64;
ProcName.m128i_i64[1] = 0xD8855EB576AF36CCui64;

ModuleName = _mm_xor_si128(_mm_load_si128(&ModuleName), ProcName);
```

Above is a snippet of code from a decompiled program that encodes(?) their strings.

ModuleName.m128i_i8 yields the string that is created in the code.

Is there any method (possibly with IDAPython or just tool already built-in) that can be used to simplify that code snippet into just ModuleName = "ntdll.dll"? (I had to compile a program to simplify it to that string)

If assembly is needed, I'll provide it.

Comment: Do you know the platform, CPU architecture, and used programming language?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understand your query

have you tried simply evaluating the xor in idc prompt

```
IDC>0x3E4D19089E7D5ED^0x6F80FFFCE583A183
```

should spit out dec,hex,oct,bin,and ascii outputs as below

```
7810418696977151086. 
6C642E6C6C64746Eh 
661441346615431072156o 0110110001100100001011100110110001101100011001000111010001101110b 
'ntdll.dl'
```